# How Merge two web sites same theme in one

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two persons each one work on the same theme wordpress but i need merge the works in one site web wordpress

I search plugins of that

Answer (score 1):

Pick one site as the one you will keep.

Make sure all your users are registered, as administrators or editors, on that site.

Then use Tools -> Export on the other site to export its posts (or pages or whatever).

Then import them to the target site.

Then shut down the site you exported from, and have your people use the single site.